# Recursive view error while using spark 3.2.0 version

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, adb

This happens while replacing temp view using below code block

```
latest_data.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView("e_test")
```

ideally this command should replace the view if e_test already exists instead it is throwing

```
"Recursive view `global_temp`.`e_test` detected (cycle: `global_temp`.`e_test` -> `global_temp`.`e_test`)" error..
```

Can someone help me with this

[codeblock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeeOj.png)

Comment: It seems this is a bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-37690

Answer (score 0):

It works with 3.0.1 but looks like the latest version has a bug

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the jupyter kernel solved it for me.